# Create dynamic link in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, button, twitter

I'm trying to create a twitter button that allows the user to share the results of a random quote generator.
This is my html:

## Quote Machine

```
 <button onclick="generateQuote()">Click me</button> 

 <p id="quotes"></p>

 <p id ="twitter"></p>
```

And this is my javascript:

```
              var quotearray =["Always be yourself","Stay in the moment","Be merry"];
 var pickAQuote = function () {
var newquote = quotearray[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
var noquotes = newquote.replace(/['"]+/g, '');
return noquotes;
};


function generateQuote() {
var newquotes = pickAQuote();

document.getElementById("quotes").innerHTML= newquotes;  
document.getElementById("twitter").innerHTML ='<button onclick=' + 
  '"https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + newquotes + '";>Tweet 
This</button>';



  }
```

So the idea is that whatever the randomly generated quote is, the user can then share that quote on twitter.  But I can't get it to work!  Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: `onclick` doesn't take you to another website, it executes JavaScript. You either want to use `window.location.href=` or replace your button with an anchor element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the url using the onClick event you should do something like this:

```
document.getElementById("twitter").innerHTML ='<button onclick="location.href = \'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + newquotes + '\'";>Tweet This</button>';
```